# Searching answers with API

Tags: support, discussion, api-v2, api

I'm very new to the API and I was looking for a way to get answers of a user. E.g. something like if you click on a tag in your tags section of your profile.

For [questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) this seems to be quiet easy but [answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

[/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-answers-in-tags)

[/users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-user-questions-in-tags)